# Renaming files that start with

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've created a batch script to automatically update some files using wget for Windows. It downloads a file with a version number in the filename, for example `server-2.0.exe`. I want to automatically rename the file to `server.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that wget has the option directly in its commands.

```
--output-document=file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might do what you want, depending on how variable the filenames are:

```
ren C:\server*.exe server.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ren server????.exe server.exe
```